# How to prevent multiple charge when using Authorize.net CIM running on cron

Tags: cron, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I'm looking for programming approaches that should be required for charging payments using cron job wisely.

The website requires recurring payments to be collected using Authorize.net. To remain PCI DSS compliance credit card info is not stored locally and uses Authorize.net CIM integration where customers enter their CC info at the hosted page. Therefore, ARB subscriptions can't be used which requires CC info to be sent from the website.

As far I know there is no possibility to create subscriptions using CIM and it requires cron jobs to charge the customer when required.

I've already integrated CIM however following are my concerns when charging customers using cron job:

1. Prevent multiple charges so that customer is not billed for same subscription twice. (My approach: I've a table which holds payments to be collected on a daily basis and a status field [varchar: paid/unpaid]. The status will change to paid if the charge is successful).
2. Server break down : If the server remains down there will be no payments collected. (My approach: The cron job will run for all payments for past 3 days with unpaid status)
3. Security measures : Need to know what sort of security measures is required?
4. Any precautionary measures which I might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

ARB through CIM is a work in progress. So you would have to initiate charge manually.
As for payments there are hundreds of ways to implement and thousands of ways things can go wrong. PCI DSS 3.0 has over 200 checklist items to take care. Basic tasks to note could be:

1. Use a proper lock mechanism to prevent race conditions
2. Log everything you are allowed to log
3. Maintain all the logs and other data on a server not accessible through web and review the read write requests on these.
4. Put request rate limits and raise warnings/block depending on activity
5. Patch all your servers OS and software, even the ones not being used or used for something else.
6. Close unnecessary open ports, and uninstall unnecessary software
7. Limit access to very few people and access through secured systems only
8. Follow rigorous code review and testing procedures
9. Check your SSL certificate [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and use strong crypto algo
10. Check against [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10)
11. Properly hash and salt user passwords and put limits on reset requests, shipping address changes etc
12. Keep an eye on updates to the softwares you are using
13. Monitor the logs for penetration requests and improve security as required

There are many more depending on your setup and requirement

Answer (score 0):

On your side, you can have a field (which you could pass as the order number) being either subscriptionNumber.dueDate or customerNumber.dueDate (meaning if your subscriptionNumber is 123 and it's 5/24/2015, being "123.05-24-2015")

Before sending to AuthNet, make sure this field is unique.  If AuthNet processes but you don't get the response, you can still have an issue.